# \[\mu\] is printing the Greek letter mu on a separate single line

Tags: symbols, greek

I want a Greek letter *mu* in between the text and when I write

```
\[\mu\]
```

in my `.tex` file, it prints on a single and separate line. How can I print it in between the text?

Comment: `\[\mu\]` is *display* math and `$\mu$` or `\(\mu\)` are *inline* math. You want the latter ones. By the way, you can mark your code with backticks rather than `*`.

Comment: Yes, thank you, it works for me perfectly :)

Comment: @Manuel That explanation would be useful in an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The command `\[\mu\]` is a short version of

```
\begin{equation*}
\mu
\end{equation*}
```

which is normally used for longer formulas. If you want to typeset (short) formulas like μ, you should use the inline-math mode, i.e.

```
This is an example text containing the greek letter $\mu$.
```

Comment: I want to write in between the text and equation print it on the new line. However $....$ works perfectly. thanks